# R identification for cycle

Tags: r, loops

I have a dataframe that lookis something like this:

```
date             | chamber | value
2016-11-06 16:43 |  1      |   ..
2016-11-06 16:44 |  1      |   ..
2016-11-06 16:45 |  2      |   ..
2016-11-06 16:46 |  2      |   ..
2016-11-06 16:47 |  3      |   ..
2016-11-06 16:48 |  3      |   ..
2016-11-06 16:49 |  1      |   ..
```

As you can see, I have data moving through time and a certain type of chambers measuring stuff. Now I need an additional variable that tells me which cycle I am in, i.e. when the cycle is complete, a new ID should be given to the new cycle, based on date and time, like this:

```
date             | chamber | value | cycle
2016-11-06 16:43 |  1      |   ..  | 201611061643
2016-11-06 16:44 |  1      |   ..  | 201611061643
2016-11-06 16:45 |  2      |   ..  | 201611061643
2016-11-06 16:46 |  2      |   ..  | 201611061643
2016-11-06 16:47 |  3      |   ..  | 201611061643
2016-11-06 16:48 |  3      |   ..  | 201611061643
2016-11-06 16:49 |  1      |   ..  | 201611061649
```

How can I do this without a for loop, since the for loop is too slow for my huge data set? Thank you

I am currently doing this, but it is way too slow (takes about 1h on my huge dataset):

```
for(i in 2:nrow(df)) # create a cycle counter
{
  df[i,]$cycle <- df[i,]$cycle
  if(df[i,]$chamber < df[i-1,]$chamberON){
    df[i,]$cycle <- format(df[i,]$date,"%Y%m%d%H%M")
  }
}
```

The question here is how to create a "cycle" variable that only changes when "chamber" comes back to value 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table` to do this.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), use `diff`, with `cumsum` to create a grouping variable and assign (`:=`) the `format` of the first 'date' as the 'cycle' column.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, cycle := format(date[1], "%Y%m%d%H%M"), cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(chamber)< 0))]
df1
#                  date chamber value        cycle
#1: 2016-11-06 16:43:00       1    .. 201611061643
#2: 2016-11-06 16:44:00       1    .. 201611061643
#3: 2016-11-06 16:45:00       2    .. 201611061643
#4: 2016-11-06 16:46:00       2    .. 201611061643
#5: 2016-11-06 16:47:00       3    .. 201611061643
#6: 2016-11-06 16:48:00       3    .. 201611061643
#7: 2016-11-06 16:49:00       1    .. 201611061649
```

---

Or another option is `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(grp =cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(chamber)< 0)) ) %>%
    mutate(cycle = format(first(date), "%Y%m%d%H%M")) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-grp)
```

Comment: Sure, but the question here is not about converting into a date. Rather note how the cycle variable should only change when chamber comes back to value 1.

Comment: @J-M  Okay, updated the post.  Previously, I didn't noticed the values

Comment: That looks promising, thanks. I'll test and report back

Comment: I really appreciate the logic used behind the grouping!!! brilliant idea @akrun. cumsum(c(T,diff(1,2,3,1)<0) is superb way of grouping !

Comment: @akrun: Thanks a lot. So your first solution works on a small dataset, but crashes R on my larger dataset (more than 200'000 rows of data) after processing for 10min. The second solution using dplyr gives me an error: answers within seconds but doesn't create the cycle column.

Comment: It appears I had a typo. Your first solution works beautifully. Thank you so much!

Comment: @akrun That's weird. Sometimes your data.table solution works and sometimes it crashes R

Comment: @J-M  Try it on a fresh R console, perhaps you assigned the same object to something else